# How can I move from iOS 11 Developer to iOS 11 Public

Tags: iphone, ios, beta

I’ve been on the developer beta since it came out, but for some stability improvements, I’d like to go to and remain on the public version. How can I move from iOS 11 Developer Beta to iOS 11 Public Beta?

Comment: What did you try to do that? Are there any differences between your case and installing iOS 11 Public Beta to a regular user device over iOS 10?

Comment: Well, upon reading that the public beta had come out, I installed the public beta configuration but when I went to look for a software update it told me I already was up to date (true, but I thought the other version's configuration profile would get me by!). The point is, though, that I guess I'm just going to have to wait for the next developer beta to come out, redownload that certificate and then update. I'd rather go to the public beta, however, if possible.

Comment: It looks like public beta is the same seed as latest iOS 11 Developer. The only difference is in naming. I can't find poof of that so I will just leave a comment, but earlier Apple used this approach for other their releases https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-upgrade-from-macOS-Sierra-Beta-to-public-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove any profiles that are in the settings app (general section)  relating to the developer program.
2. Enroll the device in the public beta program with a public beta profile.
3. Wait for the public beta build to be a newer version than your current Dev beta and then update the device.

If the Dev beta is too new or you never get an available update, you might need to erase and restore / recover the device. Since you ask this early in the 10.11 beta cycle updates should be every couple of weeks for a while. This shift isn’t a given and could break in the future even though it worked a few times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the public beta is released, the public betas and developer betas are the same, except the public beta has a slight delay on each release. You can use the developer beta like a public beta by waiting a few hours after developer beta release, then installing it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks so much for clearing that up for me.

Comment: They don’t necessarily have to be the same builds, but they have in the past overlapped well. I’ll answer with some of the actual mechanics of this - you probably need to intervene with profiles if the public one doesn’t rescind the Dev one.